# What type of certificate is required for SAML2 Logout with ADFS2?

Tags: certificate, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

What type of certificate is required for SAML2 Logout with ADFS2?  I've noticed that ADFS2 requires that LogOut request be signed by the relying party and verified within ADFS2.  I'm assuming we are supposed to sign (with private key) within the relying party and provide ADFS2 with the public key to verify.  Can I get some details as to what type of certificate is required for this?

NOTE:  I am speaking only to the SAML2 protocol and NOT WS-Federation.  WS-Federation does not require Logout requests be signed by the relying party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a self-signed certificate - the algorithm is RSA - I normally use key size 2048.

In the ADFS RP - Properties - Advanced - set the hash algorithm to SHA-1.